# PropTypes check for specific children eg. <li>, <h1>, etc

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-proptypes

Let's say, I have the following simple Component:

```
const List = ({ children, ...props }) => (
  <ul {...props}>
    {children}
  </ul>
);
```

The corresponding propTypes is the following:

```
List.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node
};
```

**How can I make the propTypes be more specific?**
So that it could accept one or more `<li>` (with any content within `<li>`), but not `<div>` for example?

Like these examples:

```
<List>
  <li>Singe item</li>
</List>

<List>
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
</List>
```

**Thank you for your help!**

Answer (score 0):

Great question! Keeping it simple, maybe you should just try using Fragment. For example

```
<List>
 <Fragment>
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
 </Fragment>
</List>
```

Comment: Well, using `React.Fragment` does not give answer to the question, that what `PropTypes` should be used for the `children` of `List`...